# array of structure of strings

Tags: java, arraylist

how can i store multiple strings in single array element in java? The strings may be added or deleted dynamically. So, the array has to be flexible. I mean, if there is an array a[], then:

```
 a[1] should be able to accommodate "String1", "String2", ....  
 a[2] should be able to accommodate "String3", "String4", ....
```

These strings may be deleted at any time and additional strings can be added any time. What java component supports this kind of functionality? I am new to java and weak at basics. Hope u can help. Thanks !

Comment: can you use a ArrayList or array of ArrayList ?

Comment: that's what i would do, an arraylist of arraylists

Comment: I would go for `Map<String, List<String>>`

Comment: For real answer, more context is needed. With that info, a container containing containers containing strings is what you need, but which container classes you should use, impossible to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need something like   `List<List<String>> yourList ;`

Remove "String2" from your List:

```
yourList.get(0).remove("String2");
```

Add "StringX" to your List at index 0.

```
 yourList.get(0).add("Stringx");
```

Comment: how do you access a particular string like "String1" in yourList(0) and how do you iterate thru all the strings in yourList(0) ? yourList(0) denotes all stings in array element 0

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to try and learn Java collections!

[Official Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)

[Tutorial 1](http://javamex.com/tutorials/collections/how_to_choose.shtml) [Tutorial 2](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=65)

This way you will have a collection for any situation you find yourself in

Answer (score 0):

You can add this strings in the same string using some using a character as delimiter and after that use a split method.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jagged arrays.  I can get a program to you to know the basics of jagged arrays: [Jagged Arrays – Varying Column Size Arrays](http://way2java.com/arrays/jagged-arrays-varying-column-size-arrays/)